# How do I measure my own blood pressure with the manual blood pressure machine?

Tags: personal-care

Don't have any person to help me around and I have the manual blood pressure measuring device.

Comment: Does not seem to need a life hack, since measuring your blood pressure with a device intended for this purpose is not an uncommon way or thinking outside the box.

Comment: @Alex Why not? A device for this purpose may be available, but it wouldn't be used in the intended way.

Comment: I'm leaving this open for the reason @Gilles noted. This is a good question!

Answer (score 3):

Performing the trial on yourself has the benefit that you can actually physically experience the points where your blood pressure is at it's highest and at it's lowest. I would recommend that you get your blood pressure measured via a digital device at a pharmacy, elsewhere, and observe how your body responds during the trial.

You should physically experience two distinct phases, one where you feel that the internal stress on your blood vessels has peaked, after which you begin releasing the pressure and experience a different state where you feel dizzy and weak from the sudden onset of oxygen. It is when you experience these two states that your systolic and diastolic readings are taken.

Wikipedia [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Blood_pressure#Noninvasive) that, to increase accuracy, for 5 minutes before the reading, one should sit upright in a chair with one's feet flat on the floor and with limbs uncrossed. The blood pressure cuff should always be against bare skin, as readings taken over a shirt sleeve are less accurate. During the reading, the arm that is used should be relaxed and kept at heart level, for example by resting it on a table.